# Prevent parent element click-event to trigger when child-dropdown clicked

Tags: javascript, firebase, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

- I have a clickable parent  element. As a child element I have a dropdown. When I click this dropdown, it also triggers the parent element.
- The table elements are rendered dynamically as rows, thus I would like to target the elements by Id and not by class.
- I have tried with e.stopPropagation() but then it prevents the dropdown to toggle.
- Very thankful for any help!

```js
document.getElementById("entirerow"+doc.id).addEventListener("click", function(e){
  alert("Entire row clicked")
})

document.getElementById("dropdown"+doc.id).addEventListener("click", function(e){
  alert("Only button clicked")
  //e.stopPropagation(); I have tried this but it prevents the dropdown from triggering at all.
})
```

```html
<tr id="entirerow"+doc.id>
  <td>
  <span>
    <button id="dropdown"+doc.id>myDropdown</button>
  </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    ...
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return early in your parent listener callback if the event target is the dropdown.

```
document.getElementById("entirerow"+doc.id).addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.id === ("dropdown"+doc.id)){
    return;
  }

  alert("Entire row clicked");
})

document.getElementById("dropdown"+doc.id).addEventListener("click", function(e){
  alert("Only button clicked");
})
```